# Orange Web Services - Problems installing imblearn module for Python Script

Tags: orange

I am trying to implement SMOTE in Orange Web Services, but having troubles with the imblearn module.

Following screenshot is from Orange Python Script widget:

```
from imblearn import under_sampling, over_sampling
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

[image]

I can import it without problems with Python:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The one in Orange's Python Script widget and the one in cmd are obviously not the same Python environments. Confirm by inspecting:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Fix the issue by installing imblearn into the Orange's Python environment.